# formatting y axis range in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

here is my code

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(~percentage, ~session,
              81,1,
              79,2,
              68,3,
              75,4,
              63,5,
              55,6,
              49,7,
              44,8,
              41,9,
              32,10)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(aes(x = session, y = percentage), data = df) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,10,by = 1))
```

and resultant graph is as follows
[image]

Here, Y-axis is from range 30 to 80. But I want it from 0 to 100. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 100))` or `coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,100))`. See the linked answer for the difference between them.